# How to make topic creater as ACL admin for that topic

Tags: apache-kafka, acl

I have a Kafka cluster on which multiple teams create their topics using JAVA client (KafkaAdmin).

Now we want to enable ACLs on those topics. I know using superuser it's possible (using Kafka CLI or Admin Client).

Is it possible to let the Kafka Topic creator be the admin for that topic and the creator should be responsible for their topics ACL?